# (udev-worker)[352]: nvidia: Process

Tags: arch-linux, udev

I get the following error messages, from the udev rules written in the 60-nvidia.rules

```
Nov 07 08:03:57 I-NET kernel: Secure boot disabled
Nov 07 08:03:58 I-NET kernel: nvidia: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
Nov 07 08:03:58 I-NET kernel: nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
Nov 07 08:03:58 I-NET kernel: nvidia: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
Nov 07 08:03:58 I-NET kernel: nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 237
Nov 07 08:03:58 I-NET kernel: nvidia 0000:01:00.0: vgaarb: changed VGA decodes: olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=none:owns=io+mem
Nov 07 08:03:58 I-NET kernel: NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  545.29.02  Thu Oct 26 21:21:38 UTC 2023
Nov 07 08:03:58 I-NET (udev-worker)[352]: nvidia: Process '/usr/bin/bash -c '/usr/bin/mknod -Z -m 666 /dev/nvidiactl c $(grep nvidia-frontend /proc/devices | cut -d \  -f 1) 255'' failed with exit code 1.
Nov 07 08:03:58 I-NET (udev-worker)[352]: nvidia: Process '/usr/bin/bash -c 'for i in $(cat /proc/driver/nvidia/gpus/*/information | grep Minor | cut -d \  -f 4); do /usr/bin/mknod -Z -m 666 /dev/nvidia${i} c $(grep nvidia-frontend /proc/devices | cut -d \  -f 1) ${i}; done'' failed with exit code 1.
Nov 07 08:03:58 I-NET (udev-worker)[343]: nvidia: Process '/usr/bin/bash -c '/usr/bin/mknod -Z -m 666 /dev/nvidiactl c $(grep nvidia-frontend /proc/devices | cut -d \  -f 1) 255'' failed with exit code 1.
Nov 07 08:03:58 I-NET (udev-worker)[343]: nvidia: Process '/usr/bin/bash -c 'for i in $(cat /proc/driver/nvidia/gpus/*/information | grep Minor | cut -d \  -f 4); do /usr/bin/mknod -Z -m 666 /dev/nvidia${i} c $(grep nvidia-frontend /proc/devices | cut -d \  -f 1) ${i}; done'' failed with exit code 1.
Nov 07 08:03:58 I-NET kernel: nvidia_uvm: module uses symbols nvUvmInterfaceDisableAccessCntr from proprietary module nvidia, inheriting taint.
Nov 07 08:03:58 I-NET kernel: nvidia-modeset: Loading NVIDIA Kernel Mode Setting Driver for UNIX platforms  545.29.02  Thu Oct 26 20:52:21 UTC 2023
Nov 07 08:03:58 I-NET (udev-worker)[352]: nvidia_modeset: Process '/usr/bin/bash -c '/usr/bin/mknod -Z -m 666 /dev/nvidia-modeset c $(grep nvidia-frontend /proc/devices | cut -d \  -f 1) 254'' failed with exit code 1.
Nov 07 08:03:58 I-NET systemd-modules-load[309]: Inserted module 'nvidia_uvm'
Nov 07 08:03:58 I-NET kernel: nvidia-uvm: Loaded the UVM driver, major device number 235.
Nov 07 08:03:58 I-NET kernel: [drm] [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Loading driver
Nov 07 08:03:58 I-NET kernel: [drm] Initialized nvidia-drm 0.0.0 20160202 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 0
Nov 07 08:03:58 I-NET kernel: input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input12
Nov 07 08:03:58 I-NET kernel: input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input13
Nov 07 08:03:58 I-NET kernel: input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input14
Nov 07 08:03:58 I-NET kernel: input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input15
```

Here are the 60-nvidia.rules

```
# Make sure device nodes are present even when the DDX is not started for the Wayland/EGLStream case
KERNEL=="nvidia", RUN+="/usr/bin/bash -c '/usr/bin/mknod -Z -m 666 /dev/nvidiactl c $$(grep nvidia-frontend /proc/devices | cut -d \  -f 1) 255'"
KERNEL=="nvidia", RUN+="/usr/bin/bash -c 'for i in $$(cat /proc/driver/nvidia/gpus/*/information | grep Minor | cut -d \  -f 4); do /usr/bin/mknod -Z -m 666 /dev/nvidia$${i} c $$(grep nvidia-frontend /proc/devices | cut -d \  -f 1) $${i}; done'"
KERNEL=="nvidia_modeset", RUN+="/usr/bin/bash -c '/usr/bin/mknod -Z -m 666 /dev/nvidia-modeset c $$(grep nvidia-frontend /proc/devices | cut -d \  -f 1) 254'"
KERNEL=="nvidia_uvm", RUN+="/usr/bin/bash -c '/usr/bin/mknod -Z -m 666 /dev/nvidia-uvm c $$(grep nvidia-uvm /proc/devices | cut -d \  -f 1) 0'"
KERNEL=="nvidia_uvm", RUN+="/usr/bin/bash -c '/usr/bin/mknod -Z -m 666 /dev/nvidia-uvm-tools c $$(grep nvidia-uvm /proc/devices | cut -d \  -f 1) 1'"
```

Is there any way to rewrite them?